# How can I write the output stream of sddp.jl into an excel file?

Tags: julia, dynamic-programming, reinforcement-learning, multi-stage-programming

I am using sddp.jl for my research project in which I am developing a state-of-the-art actor critic algorithm which I am going to benchmark with SDDP but for it I need to plot graphs which require data to be in excel or csv form.

Is there a way to transfer the output stream into excel file?

I have searched the whole internet but found nothing.

Comment: You need to perhaps save whatever data you want into eg a Julia DataFrame and than export it with XLSX.jl or write with CSV.jl.  I understand the data is some opitmization model so you will need also to decide how you are saving it (data layout)

Comment: But there is an output stream which the algorithm is keep on showing during its execution, I thing I cannot to save that with these libraries.

Comment: OK so you want to grab the output from solver logs? whatever solvers are dumping to the `stdout` and `stderr` is this what you need?

Comment: IF the answer to my question is yes have a look at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75313320/redirect-stio-and-still-printing-in-the-terminal and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69057910/how-to-collect-output-and-input-from-terminal-in-julia/69059106#69059106

Comment: Did you get the answer you needed? Is it OK if I mark this as a duplicate of the questions that I mentioned?

Comment: its fine dear actually I asked this same question on stack exchange OR and their an answer resolved my issue. Here is the link to it: https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/10896/how-can-i-write-the-output-stream-of-sddp-jl-into-an-excel-file/10899#10899